# Routing in angularjs materialdesign

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Im trying to figure out how to do routing between pages in angularjs material design.

In this example, I would like to change page when I click the sidebar link
http://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV

**Script.js**

```
// script.js

// create the module and name it scotchApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var starterApp = angular.module('starterApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
starterApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
starterApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

starterApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

starterApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

**about.html**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>About Page</h1>

    <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you write your html page about.html and other all

Comment: I am not getting exactly your problem , please explain in detail

Comment: I am trying to show another page when you click a link in the side menu. I have done this before in angularJs with the script.js. Now I am using angularJS with material design and its not working anymore and im wondering what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to put href attribute in tag `<a>`?

```
<a href="#/">Home</a>
<a href="#/about">About</a>
<a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
```

That way, whenever AngularJS sees a url change, it will trigger router to find the specified path.

Comment: Yes I tried, the url goes to /#/about but the content of the page stays the same despite the content of the about.html

Comment: Did you put <ng-view/>? I made an example and its working. http://codepen.io/marcushenrique/pen/aOzvqG

Comment: Thanks a lot your example enlighted me